# Why is it necessary for a base class to have a constructor that takes 0 args?

Tags: c#, class, constructor

This won't compile:

```
namespace Constructor0Args
{
    class Base
    {
        public Base(int x)
        {
        }
    }

    class Derived : Base
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Instead, I get the following error:

> 'Constructor0Args.Base' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Why is that? Is it necessary for a base class to have a constructor that takes 0 arguments?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It *isn't* - the problem is that it needs to call **some** base constructor, in order to initialise the base type, and the *default* is to call `base()`. You can tweak that by specifying the specific constructor (and arguments) yourself in the derived-types constructor:

```
class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived() : base(123) {}
}
```

For parameters to `base` (or alternatively, `this`) constructors, you can use:

- parameters to the *current* constructor
- literals / constants
- static method calls (also involving the above)

For example, the following is *also* valid, using all three bullets above:

```
class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived(string s) : base(int.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Any)) {}
}
```

Comment: You could also add a parameterless constructor on the base type and mark it as protected. This would allow a derived type to use the default constructor, but consumers of your type could not create an instance using it.

Comment: @Josh that is a useful pattern, especially for things like interfaces.

Answer (score 13):

When you derive a class from another, the base class will be called before the derived classes constructor. When you don't explicitly call a constructor you are essentially writing

```
class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

Since the Base class doesn't have a 0 argument constructor, this is invalid.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't explicitly define a constructor for a class, a *default constructor* is automatically defined, which looks like this:

```
public Derived() : base() 
{
}
```

You need to specify the constructor on the base class as well as which arguments to pass to it:

```
public Derived() : base(1) 
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is becase when the child class is instantiated, it will also instantiate the base class. By default, it will try to find a arg less constructor. This is work with this code:

```
class Base
    {
        public Base(int x) { }
    }
    class Derived : Base
    {
        public Derived(int x)
            : base(x)
        {
        }
    }
```