# Is it possible to make a derived class inherit a non-0 argument constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor

Building on [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966231/why-is-it-necessary-for-a-base-class-to-have-a-constructor-that-takes-0-args), is it possible to make a derived class inherit its base's constructor? For example, if I defined two classes like this:

```
class Base {
    public Base(){}
}

public Derived() {
}
```

The base class's constructor will automatically be called when the derived class is instantiated. If I add another constructor to to the base class though,

```
class Base {
    public Base(int x){}
}
```

Is it possible to construct the *derived* class using *that* constructor? I mean without having to add something like

```
public Derived() {
     public Derived(int x) : base(x) {}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't. You must explicitly add them; the **only** default is the parameterless constructor calling `base()`, which you get if you don't add any constructors. It might be nice in a few cases (especially when there are lots of constructors on the base), and I *imagine* there are some tools (maybe R# ? I haven't checked) that might help automate it - but nothing built in.

Comment: Ah. I ask because I'm building an API where users will define the derived classes, but I want them to be constructed in a particular way. That's okay though... I'll just use a setter that I'll call immediately after constructing the object.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of...

```
class Base {
    protected Base() : this(default(int)) {}
    public Base(int x){}
}

public Derived() {
}
```

Will force `Derived` to call the overloaded constructor with the default value of the argument. This may, or may not, be what you want to happen though. By marking the default constructor as `protected`, you prevent outside callers from instantiating with the default constructor but allow derived classes to do so.

Comment: Doesn't help, unfortunately. Defaults are no good, I need to pass in something determined at run-time, and I wanted to ensure that the derived class had a constructor that would accept it.

Comment: @Mark then forget setters altogether and force users that are inheriting from `Base` to call the proper base constructor. This is well defined, expected behaviour! Don't run the risk of constructing an object that isn't valid. `public Derived(int x) : base(x) {}` is exactly what you want and what most developers would expect.

Comment: Why should I force users to add that exact snippet of code to every one of their classes? And I'm not running any risk, because *I'm* the one constructing the classes, so I can immediately call the setter afterword, putting it into a valid state, and I don't have to run that risk because users don't have to call it themselves, whereas they can forget to include that constructor, or worse, implement it incorrectly.